# Xpath 1 (dom4j) - concatenate text values of multiple nodes

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

Is there a way to concatenate text values of several nodes using Xpath 1? I know what in Xpath 2 there's a cool `string-join` function, but dom4j supports only first version.

For example I have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
    <item>c</item>
</root>
```

I want to get (for example) "a,b,c" string using Xpath 1. Is it possible?

UPD: item count is unknown

Answer (score 2):

if you exactly know the structure you can

```
concat(//item[1],',',//item[2],',',//item[3])
```

result

```
String='a,b,c'
```

Comment: then only loop with `//item`, i think

Comment: you mean loop in Java code? Unfortunately I need to do it just by Xpath :(

Comment: in any language. If only by xpath, i think, no

Comment: it's sad :( So obviously thing